# Generate Python file from Python code

Tags: python

I have to create a Python file on the fly, using Python code (functions, classes, imports). This is the code that I currently have

```
def write_code_to_file(code_list, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as ofh:
        for c in code_list:
            fh = io.StringIO(inspect.getsource(c))
            ofh.writelines(fh.readlines())
            ofh.write('\n\n')


write_code_to_file([myFunc, myClass],'/some/path')
```

1) Is there a better way of doing this?

2) How do I do import statements? I can pass a string directly i.e. "from lib import util" but is there a better way of doing it? I can't assign an import statement to a variable but how could I do something like.

```
import_stmt1 = ...something which represents "from lib import util" ....

write_code_to_file([import_stmt1, myFunc], '/tmp/myfile.py')
```

So, when I open `/tmp/myfile.py`, it should be:

```
from lib import util

def myFunc(arg1, arg2..)
  ...
```

Comment: __import()__ would help you with your second question: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__

Comment: `import()` would import the source code for the entire module, won't it? i.e. the entire source in my `util.py`. I just need to import the line `from lib import util`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am starting to understand what you're trying to do. I thought you  were trying to import a module you built on the fly, you are trying to see how to import.

Thing is that importing does somethings to the module in memory. If you do something like:

```
import myMod
myMod.__dict__
```

You will see how import loads all the functions of the imported modules into the myMod dictionary.  This is probably how you would do it in code. You may want to look at creating your own module dictionaries, aka using metaprogramming (http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html).